# Distance command and tag command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was experimenting with some command blocks and tried to make it so that when you had different colours of wool in a specific order in your inventory it would give you certain special abilities. The command sequence I used was:

Command block 1, repeating

```
execute @e[type=minecraft:snowball] if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:6b,id:"minecraft:red_wool"}]},nbt={Inventory: [{Slot:7b,id:"minecraft:blue_wool"}]},nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:8b,id:"minecraft:yellow_wool"}]},distance=1] run tag @s add path
```

Command block 2, repeating

```
execute @e[tag=path,type=snowball] run setblock ~ ~-2 ~ white_wool keep
```

The snowball should leave behind a path of white wool wherever it is thrown, as long as the player throwing it has the specific wool sequence in their inventory. The problem is that it wont work and I'm not sure why. I got it to work where all snowballs thrown leave behind a path if one player has the sequence, but I want it to be only snowballs thrown by a specific player. I also tried by giving the player snowballs with tags but the tag disappears when you throw the snowball.